# Converting an int to a String and then encrypt it with XOR

Tags: java, string, encryption, character-encoding, int

I'm trying to convert an Integer to a String, and then encrypt the String with a XOR encryption. But when i'm decrypting my Strin again, i get a different answer, that the String i typed before the encryption, and i don't know what i'm doing wrong?

```
public class Krypte {
public static void main (String [] args) {
    int i = 12345;

    String k = Integer.toString(i);
    String G = secure(k.getBytes());
    System.out.println("Encrypted: " + G);

    String U = secure(G.getBytes());
    System.out.println("Decrypted: " + U);
    int X = Integer.parseInt(U);
    System.out.println("As an int: " + X);

}

public static String secure(byte[] msg) {
    // Variables
    int outLength = msg.length;
    byte secret = (byte) 0xAC; // same as 10101100b (Key)
    // XOR kryptering
    for (int i = 0; i < outLength; i++) {
        // encrypting each byte with XOR (^)
        msg[i] = (byte) (msg[i] ^ secret);
    }
    return new String(msg);
}
}
```

Comment: Sorry my bad. But can you help me with my coding problem, and not my understanding (misunderstanding) about encryption?

Comment: Ask yourself: "what is a String"? Strings are *not* sequences of arbitrary bytes. Read the Java docs for [String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) to help answer that question, and you'll begin to understand why your code doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a subtle (yet very important) difference between `char` and `byte` types. Consider this:

```
class Krypte {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        int i = 12345;
        String k = Integer.toString(i);
        System.out.println("Before: " + k);    
        String G = secure(k.toCharArray());
        System.out.println("Encrypted: " + G);
        String U = secure(G.toCharArray());
        System.out.println("Decrypted: " + U);
        int X = Integer.parseInt(U);
        System.out.println("As an int: " + X);
    }

    public static String secure(char[] msg) {
        // Variables
        int outLength = msg.length;
        byte secret = (byte) 0xAC; // same as 10101100b (Key)
        // XOR kryptering
        for (int i = 0; i < outLength; i++) {
            // encrypting each byte with XOR (^)
            System.out.println("Byte before: " + msg[i]);
            msg[i] = (char) (msg[i] ^ secret);
            System.out.println("Byte after: " + msg[i]);
        }
        return new String(msg);
    }
}
```

This works ([proof](http://ideone.com/DLGpZE)), because XORing some *character* value with a byte will ([most probably](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Invalid_code_points)) give you a valid *character*.

Not let's see what happens in [the original snippet](http://ideone.com/CMFxx8) - by adding this debugging output into the main loop of `secure` method:

```
 System.out.println("Byte before: " + msg[i]);
 msg[i] = (byte) (msg[i] ^ secret);
 System.out.println("Byte after: " + msg[i]);
```

And the output would be:

```
Byte before: 49
Byte after: -99
Byte before: 50
Byte after: -98
Byte before: 51
Byte after: -97
Byte before: 52
Byte after: -104
Byte before: 53
Byte after: -103
```

It's quite ok: first `getBytes` function *encoded* the string given into an array of bytes using the platform's *default charset*. Character `'1'` gets encoded into `49` byte value; `'2'` becomes `50`, etc.

Then we're XORing these values with our key - and get this sequence of bytes:

```
-99 -98 -97 -104 -103
```

The final step seems easy: we just make (and return) a new String from this sequence of bytes, what can go wrong here? But in fact it's the very step where, well, the fan get hit. )

See, `String` constructor tries to process this sequence of bytes *using the platform's default charset*. Indeed, for some charsets these bytes represent a sequence of valid characters just fine - but not for UTF-8!

...You probably already guessed what happens next. For each 'undecodable' sequence of bytes, as [described here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Invalid_byte_sequences), the *first* byte is transformed into so-called [Replacement character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replacement_character#Replacement_character), and others are retried. In this particular example there would be five of these signs of failure in the string returned by the first `secure` invokation.

Decoding this string is, well, quite meaningless - as it doesn't store any information (except length) about the target string. That's why the original code ultimately failed.